# how to play audio from A2DP enabled headset? I have ubuntu 11.10 system

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to play few audio files from my Ubuntu 11.10 system.
and don't know which A2DP enabled blue-tooth head set would be required.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Nokia BH-503 headset. Please also see this post https://askubuntu.com/a/147115/37991 if you get any latency or audio breaks.