# Accidentally changed Bluetooth mode to off

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth, a2dp

My Bluetooth device disappeared after I changed its mode from High Fidelity A2DP to off. Is this a bug? How can I get my speaker back into the audio menu?

I tried disconnecting and reconnecting. But it seems that Ubuntu remembers the Bluetooth setting and leaves it off.

Comment: try this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/837732/33292

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've experienced this too, though it was not in the 'off' profile, but telephony profile for some reason.

Try installing `pavucontrol`, start it up (PulseAudio Volume Control), and reselect the A2DP profile used for your audio device there in the tab 'Configuration'. It should remember the profile the next time you plug in (or connect for Bluetooth).

[image: Screenshot of pavucontrol for A2DP profile selection.]

For a command-line way of doing this, try

```
BLUEZCARD=`pactl list cards short | egrep -o bluez.*[[:space:]]`
pactl set-card-profile $BLUEZCARD a2dp
```

As can be found in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/171165/88802) (by @izx).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm really new into this Linux Stuff and it seems that device Management is really painful on Ubuntu if you come from a PC. I can't understand why the normal Audio Control has so less options. But Anyhow. You are my hero! I would flipped out without you. Thank you again! :)

Comment: That sound menu, should bring you to the full fledged Sound software, you should have the option there.

Comment: @UriHerrera From the question: "my Bluetooth Device disapeared". Therefore I guess it breaks for him, supposedly. ``pavucontrol`` is just an alternative GUI to make Pulseaudio/bluez apply this profile change.