# Bluetooth headset without crystal clear sound

Tags: windows-7, kubuntu, bluetooth, headset, noise

I've started using Kubuntu 12.04 1 week ago, and i'm having a little issue. I can connect my bluetooth headset without any problem, but the sound coming from the headset isn't crystal clear. I can have a really nice sound on Windows 7, but i can't find a way to make it happen on Kubuntu. Like i said, i'm a early user. Sorry for my english.

Comment: The English isn't much of a problem. The description is, however. What do you mean by "isn't crystal clear"? What does the noise sound like? White noise, cracking, thumping?

Answer (score 1):

Provided you run KDE with pulseaudio you will have access to the audio profile for your Bluetooth headset by installing and running [pavucontrol](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pavucontrol&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

You need the `A2DP` protocol for high fidelity sound output. How to do this is illustrated in the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/187917/) of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187915/).

Comment: OH MY GOD!! This just made my bluetooth go crystal clear!! I'm a noob linux user. I'm not lying when i say that see something working so easily, gave me goosebumps! I'm in love with Kubuntu. Beside everything, you guys are SO patient! Thanks Takkat, and thanks everyone!