# Ubuntu 18.04: Bluetooth device disconnects right after connect on Lenovo P50

Tags: bluetooth, lenovo, 18.04, disconnect

After upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04, any device I connect to only stays connected for a couple of seconds. My laptop is a Lenovo P50 (20ENCTO1WW)

/var/log/syslog reports:

```
pulseaudio[????]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: Information about device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_???????? invalid
bluetoothd[????]: Endpoint replied with an error: org.bluez.Error.InvalidArguments
```

Obviously the question marks represent some id's (pid's and bluetooth id in this case)

Any clue on fix or workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution which has worked for months, was to upgrade to a newer version of bluez, as described here: [Bluetooth doesn't work after resuming from sleep, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036195/bluetooth-doesnt-work-after-resuming-from-sleep-ubuntu-18-04-lts?rq=1). But recently I experienced regression: I get the same behaviour as before. But in an attempt to solve it, I downgraded to an old version of bluez and later upgraded back to the same version that stopped working properly (5.50-0ubuntu0ppa1 in my case) which solved the problem for now. So reinstalling seems to fix or mitigate something. Seems likely this can happen again sometime in the future ...

Answer (score 82):

I had the same issue and solved it with the following steps:

`sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`

`killall pulseaudio`

Try to connect again.

[Solution source](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/547)

Comment: This one worked for my  Bluetooth headphones.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem on other laptop using 20.04, and this solution WORKED for me.

Comment: worked on my dell vostro ubuntu18.04

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04!

Comment: i had the same problem when connecting my android to 21.04, worked immediately..............

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: This worked on 22.04. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't work for me on 22.04 :(

Comment: Worked for me in hp elitebook

Comment: I had problems with my headphones connecting but not showing up in audio output devices. Then my headphones kept disconnecting. This solved all of my problems. I had Pulseaudio already installed but I just had to kill it once/update it after switching to Ubuntu 22 and now everything just works!

Answer (score 20):

I ran into this issue on my Lenovo P51 running Ubuntu 18.04, and I discovered that the pactl module "module-bluetooth-discover" was not loading properly at boot time. I fixed the issue by replacing it with "module-bluez5-discover" in my pulse configuration.

You can test this by running:
`sudo pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-discover`
`sudo pactl load-module module-bluez5-discover`

And try to repair/reconnect your devices. If it works, replicate the following configuration in your /etc/pulse/default.pa config.

```
# Modify: /etc/pulse/default.pa
# Comment out the following line

.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
.endif

# Replace it with ...

.ifexists module-bluez5-discover.so
load-module module-bluez5-discover
.endif
```

My suspicion is that this is a change that was made during the switch from Unity to Gnome and the leftover configurations remained, leaving the standard Bluetooth modules behind which don't load correctly.

After switching to bluez5, I have since had no issues, and Bluetooth connects without complaint on my mobile phone, mouse, and headset. :)

EDIT: I also followed several steps mentioned here: [Bluetooth doesn't work after resuming from sleep, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036195/bluetooth-doesnt-work-after-resuming-from-sleep-ubuntu-18-04-lts?noredirect=1&lq=1)

To exactly replicate my configuration, make sure you `apt-get install bluez blueman pulseaudio` to have all the same packages. As was suggested in the referenced problem, I believe this was caused by upgrading to 18.04 from 17.04.

Comment: Hey. When I ran `pactl load-module module-bluez5-discovery`. got this message `Failure: Module initialization failed` any idea how to debug?

Comment: I edited the mistakes in the "pactl" command (removed the y after discover and also added sudo...

Comment: Make sure to follow the install steps described by @Dark Singularity in the "EDIT" section of their answer!

Comment: I'm getting `Home directory not accessible: Permission denied` as `sudo` and `Failure: Module initialization failed` as user.

Answer (score 12):

I also have this problem with my NC75 Pro headset from time to time. [Dark Singularity's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1050172/247771) and ubuntu upgrade did not work for me.

The only workaround I found is to remove the device and install it again:

[image]

If it won't connect at all, maybe you have to update the driver as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1202186/247771).

Comment: Oh right!  I've done that in the past, but for some reason forgot about doing this.  I can confirm that it worked for my headset in Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with 20.04. I've posted my workaround in the following question, but unfortunately haven't found a complete solution:

[Ubuntu 20.04 + Gnome 3.36.8: Bluetooth headset disconnects straight after connect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419926/ubuntu-20-04-gnome-3-36-8-bluetooth-headset-disconnects-straight-after-connec)

Answer (score -1):

Install `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`:

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

Then restart pulseaudio:

```
pulseaudio -k ; pulseaudio -D
```

Finally, try connecting again in the Bluetooth manager. You might also need to change some sound settings (type "sound" into the main menu) or reload the tab/program playing audio for everything to work properly.

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove the device on Pulse Audio Bluetooth Devices
2. Kill pulse audio and restart the Bluetooth service

```sh
sudo killall pulseaudio && sudo service bluetooth restart
```