# Bluetooth disappears when I suspend the pc or close the lid

Tags: bluetooth, suspend, power-management, 21.10, bluez

My bluetooth disappears when I suspend the pc.
I heard it's a pretty common problem. On all questions on this website, the answer was always to upgrade bluez because the version 5.28 was buggy. On my machine running Ubuntu 21.04 the version of bluez is `Version: 5.60-0ubuntu2.1`, the latest one.

After I resume my pc, is seems like there's no bluetooth card in my pc. I get the following screen:

I tried everything suggested in this post:
[Bluetooth doesn't work after resuming from sleep, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036195/bluetooth-doesnt-work-after-resuming-from-sleep-ubuntu-18-04-lts) from 2018.

Is there anyone who has a solution to my problem? I had this problem both on Ubuntu 21.10 and Pop!_OS 21.10?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried reinstalling the `bluez` using the following commands:

1. `sudo apt remove bluez`
2. `sudo apt install bluez`

You also need to run this command to get bluetooth audio to work:

- `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` [Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1186839/1564917)

I hope this helps, or based on when you posted, I hope this helps anyone that gets here with the same issue!