# Unpair Bluetoth device without going to command line

Tags: bluetooth

I know how to unpair a Bluetooth device from the command line, using **bluetoothctl**.  But is it possible  to do this without resorting to the command line interface?

Comment: You're not able to do so from the GUI settings manager?

Comment: I see nothing in System Settings for this.

Comment: You don't have a section for Bluetooth in the settings at all? Which version and flavour of Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm running Kubuntu 22.10. The Bluetooth settings are per-device only.  I can disconnect a device, but I can't unpair it.  That becomes a problem when I want to connect it to a different computer.

Comment: It's the "Remove Device" button as seen, e.g., in https://askubuntu.com/a/1200067/158442 But that's not going to help your problem. Unpairing a device is a one-sided operation; unpairing A from B doesn't remove B from A's pairings.