# My Bluetooth crashes whenever I skip a song on Rhythmbox

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, rhythmbox

I have been having an odd bluetooth issue, where my headphones will connect and work totally fine until I try and do something in [Rhythmbox](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox).  I have mostly noticed that it will stop working whenever I hit next song, but I think it actually happens whenever I do any Rhythmbox command, like pausing too.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, with pulseaudio 11.1, [rhythmbox](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox) 3.4.2 and blueman-manager 2.0.5.

I tried running

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

which gives me this message:

```
[ ok ] Restarting bluetooth (via systemctl): bluetooth.service.
Failure: Module initialization failed
```

and followed the top 2 solutions to that problem discussed here: [PulseAudio can not load bluetooth module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689281/pulseaudio-can-not-load-bluetooth-module)
but none of that has worked for me. The only thing that has been successful is restarting my computer, but even then it only works until I skip a song.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution shortly after posting sorry for all the fuss!

For others with this issue, I installed Pulse Audio Volume Control as suggested here [No sound from bluetooth headset, but it's detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239209/no-sound-from-bluetooth-headset-but-its-detected)

I just had to switch the Rhythmbox output, which was still going to my computer speakers for some reason even though the system sounds were correctly going to my headphones.