# Yet another question on connecting bluetooth headphones

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

My bluetooth headphones (Sony WF-1000XM3) don't connect correctly (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, didn't work on previous versions either). I've been trying out various proposed solutions from similar questions on this site, and [one of them](https://askubuntu.com/a/837732/1624151) actually worked. Once.
I have no idea what I might have done differently then, but I noticed a difference in behavior that might tell you something:
Usually, when connecting to the headphones (which only works by removing the connection and setting them up again), the "Connection" slider in the bluetooth settings is greyed out.
The headphones do not recognize this connection, and they aren't available as a sound output device. Often they immediately disconnect.

[image: Bluetooth settings for headphones]

The one time the script linked above worked, the "Connection" switch worked.

Pairing via `bluetoothctl` gives the following output:

```
[bluetooth]# pair 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48
Attempting to pair with 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 Connected: yes
[DEL] Device 30:B8:E7:9D:40:1B 30-B8-E7-9D-40-1B
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 UUIDs: 00000709-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 UUIDs: 0000fe03-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 UUIDs: 55f80aef-d89f-41a4-9e36-0ffc88dc81ce
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 UUIDs: 5b833e05-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 UUIDs: 5b833e06-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 UUIDs: 67a846ad-de3e-451b-a6d8-7b2899ca2370
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 UUIDs: 91c10d9c-aaef-42bd-b6d6-8a648c19213d
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 UUIDs: dc405470-a351-4a59-97d8-2e2e3b207fbb
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 UUIDs: fe59bfa8-7fe3-4a05-9d94-99fadc69faff
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 Paired: yes
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0051
    dc405470-a351-4a59-97d8-2e2e3b207fbb
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0051/char0052
    bfd869fa-a3f2-4c2f-bcff-3eb1ec80cead
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0051/char0054
    2a6b6575-faf6-418c-923f-ccd63a56d955
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0051/char0054/desc0056
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0060
    5b833e06-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0060/char0061
    5b833c10-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0060/char0063
    5b833c12-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0060/char0063/desc0065
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0070
    5b833e05-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0070/char0071
    5b833c11-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0070/char0073
    5b833c13-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0070/char0073/desc0075
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0070/char0076
    5b833c14-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090
    fe59bfa8-7fe3-4a05-9d94-99fadc69faff
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090/char0091
    69745240-ec29-4899-a2a8-cf78fd214303
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090/char0091/desc0093
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090/char0094
    104c022e-48d6-4dd2-8737-f8ac5489c5d4
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090/char0096
    70efdf00-4375-4a9e-912d-63522566d947
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090/char0096/desc0098
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090/char0099
    eea2e8a0-89f0-4985-a1e2-d91dc4a52632
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090/char009b
    a79e2bd1-d6e4-4d1e-8b4f-141d69011cbb
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0
    67a846ad-de3e-451b-a6d8-7b2899ca2370
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0/char00a1
    9fbf120d-6301-42d9-8c58-25e699a21dbd
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0/char00a1/desc00a3
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0/char00a4
    69d1d8f3-45e1-49a8-9821-9bbdfdaad9d9
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0/char00a6
    22eac6e9-24d6-4bb5-be44-b36ace7c7bfb
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0/char00a6/desc00a8
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0/char00a9
    753eed35-a584-45bb-baed-67fc7b2dc142
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0/char00a9/desc00ab
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0
    55f80aef-d89f-41a4-9e36-0ffc88dc81ce
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0/char00b1
    2f7cabce-808d-411f-9a0c-bb92ba96c102
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0/char00b1/desc00b3
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0/char00b4
    c6b2f38c-23ab-46d8-a6ab-a3a870bbd5d7
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0/char00b6
    9b3c81d8-57b1-4a8a-b8df-0e56f7ca51c2
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0/char00b6/desc00b8
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0/char00b9
    3adf41af-f7a1-4e16-863e-53a188d5bf8d
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0/char00b9/desc00bb
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0
    91c10d9c-aaef-42bd-b6d6-8a648c19213d
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00c1
    99d1064e-4517-46aa-8fb4-6be64dd1a1f1
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00c1/desc00c3
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00c4
    fbe87f6c-3f1a-44b6-b577-0bac731f6e85
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00c4/desc00c6
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00c7
    420791c0-bff5-4bd1-b957-371614031136
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00c7/desc00c9
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00ca
    e4ef5a46-30f9-4287-a3e7-643066acb768
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00ca/desc00cc
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00d0
    0000fe03-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Amazon.com Services, Inc.
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00d0/char00d1
    f04eb177-3005-43a7-ac61-a390ddf83076
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00d0/char00d3
    2beea05b-1879-4bb4-8a2f-72641f82420b
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00d0/char00d3/desc00d5
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00e0
    00000709-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Unknown
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00e0/char00e1
    9884d812-61fe-4a24-94d3-b2c11a851fac
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00e0/char00e3
    dfd4416e-e40c-47f7-8248-eb8be3dc47f9
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00e0/char00e3/desc00e5
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
Pairing successful
```

And connecting yields

```
[bluetooth]# connect 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48
Attempting to connect to 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 Name: LE_WF-1000XM3
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 Alias: LE_WF-1000XM3
Connection successful
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0051
    dc405470-a351-4a59-97d8-2e2e3b207fbb
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0051/char0052
    bfd869fa-a3f2-4c2f-bcff-3eb1ec80cead
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0051/char0054
    2a6b6575-faf6-418c-923f-ccd63a56d955
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0051/char0054/desc0056
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0060
    5b833e06-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0060/char0061
    5b833c10-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0060/char0063
    5b833c12-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0060/char0063/desc0065
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0070
    5b833e05-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0070/char0071
    5b833c11-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0070/char0073
    5b833c13-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0070/char0073/desc0075
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0070/char0076
    5b833c14-6bc7-4802-8e9a-723ceca4bd8f
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090
    fe59bfa8-7fe3-4a05-9d94-99fadc69faff
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090/char0091
    69745240-ec29-4899-a2a8-cf78fd214303
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090/char0091/desc0093
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090/char0094
    104c022e-48d6-4dd2-8737-f8ac5489c5d4
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090/char0096
    70efdf00-4375-4a9e-912d-63522566d947
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090/char0096/desc0098
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090/char0099
    eea2e8a0-89f0-4985-a1e2-d91dc4a52632
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service0090/char009b
    a79e2bd1-d6e4-4d1e-8b4f-141d69011cbb
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0
    67a846ad-de3e-451b-a6d8-7b2899ca2370
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0/char00a1
    9fbf120d-6301-42d9-8c58-25e699a21dbd
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0/char00a1/desc00a3
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0/char00a4
    69d1d8f3-45e1-49a8-9821-9bbdfdaad9d9
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0/char00a6
    22eac6e9-24d6-4bb5-be44-b36ace7c7bfb
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0/char00a6/desc00a8
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0/char00a9
    753eed35-a584-45bb-baed-67fc7b2dc142
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00a0/char00a9/desc00ab
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0
    55f80aef-d89f-41a4-9e36-0ffc88dc81ce
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0/char00b1
    2f7cabce-808d-411f-9a0c-bb92ba96c102
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0/char00b1/desc00b3
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0/char00b4
    c6b2f38c-23ab-46d8-a6ab-a3a870bbd5d7
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0/char00b6
    9b3c81d8-57b1-4a8a-b8df-0e56f7ca51c2
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0/char00b6/desc00b8
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0/char00b9
    3adf41af-f7a1-4e16-863e-53a188d5bf8d
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00b0/char00b9/desc00bb
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0
    91c10d9c-aaef-42bd-b6d6-8a648c19213d
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00c1
    99d1064e-4517-46aa-8fb4-6be64dd1a1f1
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00c1/desc00c3
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00c4
    fbe87f6c-3f1a-44b6-b577-0bac731f6e85
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00c4/desc00c6
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00c7
    420791c0-bff5-4bd1-b957-371614031136
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00c7/desc00c9
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00ca
    e4ef5a46-30f9-4287-a3e7-643066acb768
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00c0/char00ca/desc00cc
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00d0
    0000fe03-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Amazon.com Services, Inc.
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00d0/char00d1
    f04eb177-3005-43a7-ac61-a390ddf83076
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00d0/char00d3
    2beea05b-1879-4bb4-8a2f-72641f82420b
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00d0/char00d3/desc00d5
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00e0
    00000709-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Unknown
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00e0/char00e1
    9884d812-61fe-4a24-94d3-b2c11a851fac
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00e0/char00e3
    dfd4416e-e40c-47f7-8248-eb8be3dc47f9
    Vendor specific
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_3F_A6_E2_DF_48/service00e0/char00e3/desc00e5
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 Paired: yes
[CHG] Controller 4C:79:6E:FB:23:6C Discoverable: yes
[CHG] Device 5A:C7:46:C8:9A:CF RSSI: -92
[CHG] Device D0:4F:7E:08:72:3B RSSI: -95
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -62
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 TxPower: -12
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 ServiceData Key: 0000fe2c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 ServiceData Value:
  38 c9 5c                                         8.\             
[CHG] Device D0:4F:7E:08:72:3B RSSI: -96
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -55
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -64
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -55
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -55
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -60
[CHG] Device D0:4F:7E:08:72:3B RSSI: -95
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -60
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -60
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -55
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -55
[CHG] Device 5A:C7:46:C8:9A:CF RSSI: -95
[NEW] Device 46:AB:68:AF:3B:B3 46-AB-68-AF-3B-B3
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -62
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -59
[CHG] Device 5A:C7:46:C8:9A:CF RSSI: -95
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -56
[CHG] Device 5A:C7:46:C8:9A:CF RSSI: -95
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -55
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -62
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -55
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:E2:DF:48 RSSI: -59
```

This results in the same situation described above (greyed-out connection switch, headphones not selectable as sound output).

Do you have an idea on how to fix this, or how to diagnose what the problem actually is?

Comment: So there is a driver installed for it. Make sure there are no other devices nearby that you use these on and that have BT active. Install if not already and use the command line tool `bluetoothctl` to connect. Likely that shows a message/error, If so add it to the q.

Comment: Done! Surprisingly this is not something that I'd identify as an error message.

Comment: that is only pairing now connect to it

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, added it.

Comment: seems to be working. RSSI is the signal strength.

Comment: What result from terminal for `pactl list short | grep blue`

Comment: This morning the headphones miraculously work. I expect that this isn't permanent though. I'll add the results of the above once it has stopped working again!

Comment: @Monoidoid were you able to find a solution for this problem other than the miracle ? Facing the same issue with my Sony WI-C100.

Comment: @evzine Sadly no. While my headphones usually don't immediately connect to the PC, I can switch the connection on in the bluetooth settings and then run the script from the answer linked above. The only recommendation I can give to you is to try the script :|