# Ubuntu 22.04 not Recognizing Bluetooth headphones as audio device

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

My JBL Tour One headphones can connect to my laptop but will not show up as an audio device. Sometimes I can get them to show up after factory resetting them, but i'ts not reliable. This is the output of `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`:

```
[190711.486357] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x 401 failed: -16
[190753.168762] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2005 failed: -22
[190753.168775] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x200b failed: -22
```

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/questions/239209/no-sound-from-bluetooth-headset-but-its-detected

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1184363/1651993) worked for me after a little bit of work, however whenever I connect them the balance is set all the way to the left

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my JBL Aero Pro. The solution was to plug them into my ear and then go into "pairing" mode. From the quick start guide this was done by a quick click followed by a long (5s) hold on my right earpiece. It said "pairing" (not sure all JBL earbuds will do that).

Next I simply found them on the list of bluetooth devices with Ubuntu bluetooth control panel - and when connected it was paired and now show up as an audio device (both output and input).

[image: Bluetooth Device Details]