# JBL LIVE PRO 2 TWS-LE pairs but not showing up as an input/output

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, blueman

My Ubuntu 22.04LTS Laptop (Precision 7670 w/Intel Bluetooth Device) has no issues connecting to and using Bluetooth devices until I tried to pair the latest JBL LIVE PRO 2 TWS-LE earbuds with it. Blueman connects and shows the device as a Headset however Ubuntu's audio stack only shows my laptop's build in speakers as selectable.  I tried another set of Bluetooth earbuds and those work just fine so I suspect it's an issue with Intel BT, and Ubuntu's audio stack with the latest earbuds from JBL since bluetoothctl shows the device.  Any other ideas?

```
# bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[JBL LIVE PRO 2 TWS-LE]# 
[JBL LIVE PRO 2 TWS-LE]# info
Device 28:6F:40:A9:BC:79 (public)
    Name: JBL LIVE PRO 2 TWS-LE
    Alias: JBL LIVE PRO 2 TWS-LE
    Class: 0x00240404
    Icon: audio-headset
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Amazon.com Services, Inc. (0000fe03-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Google                    (0000fe2c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (65786365-6c70-6f69-6e74-2e636f6d0000)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (66666666-6666-6666-6666-666666666666)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (81c2e72a-0591-443e-a1ff-05f988593351)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (931c7e8a-540f-4686-b798-e8df0a2ad9f7)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (df21fe2c-2515-4fdb-8886-f12c4d67927c)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (f8d1fbe4-7966-4334-8024-ff96c9330e15)
    Modalias: bluetooth:v0ECBp2058d001F
[JBL LIVE PRO 2 TWS-LE]# export
SHELL=0x565330edd8d0
HISTORY=0x565330c5d390
DBUS_CONNECTION=0x565330f14700
/org/bluez/hci0=0x565330f1a2c0
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_6A_8E_17_0F_BB=0x565330f1cef0
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_04_5D_4B_98_A7_AE=0x565330f1f0d0
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_98_09_CF_62_EE_1C=0x565330f212e0
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_81_F4_9B_64_76=0x565330f26b00
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_28_6F_40_A9_BC_79=0x565330f28590
[JBL LIVE PRO 2 TWS-LE]#
```

Answer (score 2):

This other thread here helped me solve the same problem.

[Ubuntu 22.04 not Recognizing Bluetooth headphones as audio device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1458612/ubuntu-22-04-not-recognizing-bluetooth-headphones-as-audio-device)

First turn off the laptop bluetooth. Then you have to do a quick click followed by a 5 second hold on the right earbud. This will make the earbuds enter pairing mode.

Then you turn on the bluetooth. In my case pairing with the "JBL LIVE PRO 2 TWS-LE" didn´t work. I had to pair with the earbud when it showed up as "JBL LIVE PRO 2 TWS".

I had to repeat this proccess a few times until it showed up on the list as "JBL LIVE PRO 2 TWS".

Bluetooth devices list image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn off the laptop bluetooth under `Settings -> Bluetooth`.
2. To enter pairing mode, do a quick click followed by a 5 second hold on the right earbud. You will hear the word "pairing" in the earbud when it has entered pairing mode.
3. Turn on the bluetooth from `Settings -> Bluetooth`.
4. Open a terminal and run `bluetoothctl` then from within the bluetoothctl shell run `scan on`.
5. Switch back to the settings page `Settings -> Bluetooth` and watch for your device to show up.

```
$ bluetoothctl 
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...[bluetooth]# Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
...
[bluetooth]# <- lots of devices might show up depending on how many bluetooth devices are nearby
...
[bluetooth]# [NEW] Device 28:6D:40:A9:BA:CD JBL LIVE PRO 2 TWS
[CHG] Device 28:6D:40:A9:BA:CD Connected: yes
```