# How to troubleshoot and collect bug information for Bluetooth mouse lag on high CPU load?

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, cpu-load, input-devices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to debug lag using Bluetooth connected mouse and A2DP headset?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189711/how-to-debug-lag-using-bluetooth-connected-mouse-and-a2dp-headset)

I have just migrate to 12.10 and I have noticed that I have huge problem with my Bluetooth mouse left click button on a high load (wired, but scroll and right button are not affected). I think powersave cpu mode affect that more than cpu load. It just not "trigger the interrupt".

Mouse is laggy, click are not registered. I cannot work like that. At the same time, my touchpad and usb mouse works great.

How do I check the - limit cpu frequency (I use powersave and ondemend mode)?

I now wonder, what should I log, check, measure, to capture enough data to fill bug report.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, I've changed cpu mode:
powersave -> ondemend (mouse working ok) -> powersave (mouse still working well)
so I'm a bit confused...