# Lag in sound via Bluetooth headset and problem in high fidality playback (A2DP sink)

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, youtube, headset

Earlier I was using Ubuntu 14.04 and everything is fine but when I shifted to Ubuntu 16.04 , I am facing minor issue.

- First Lag in sound via Bluetooth headset. lag is about 3..4 second
- Sometimes YouTube stuck playing to fix it I have to change headset setting from **high fidelity  playback (A2DP sink)** to **headset head unit** then disconnect Bluetooth from headset connect again then change back to **high fidelity  playback (A2DP sink)**.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? I've the same problem and it took me a while to figure out that this is where the issue lies. Seems to be something related to graphics; for example, scrolling around a webpage while watching a YouTube video will cause the audio to jitter, and be delayed (out of sync with video).

Comment: Seems related to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/934472/a2dp-sound-delayed

Comment: @Codesleuth the link is broken. But this question might be related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145935/get-rid-of-0-5s-latency-when-playing-audio-over-bluetooth-with-a2dp

As is this, one, but this one is unanswered: https://askubuntu.com/questions/979714/ubuntu-17-10-bluetooth-delays

I am affected by the same issue.