# Ubuntu 17.10 Bluetooth Delays

Tags: sound, video, bluetooth, 17.10, bluetooth-speaker

just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10. Bluetooth works well for my small Logitech X100 speaker. Unfurtunately, on youtube videos it just needs a little bit time and there comes an delay only on the audio. It's not a youtube or hardware problem because when I switch to the internal speakers on the fly, the delay is gone.

Really strange though, when I switch backward-forward a bit on youtube videos, the delay remains. But as I said, only for Bluetooth speakers not for the internal speakers.

Looks like the delay is in the bluetooth cache, if something exists. Maybe its not big enough to handle videos? o.O
Any ideas what I can do?

PS: Just a small additional information. The delay appears for all sounds (also system sounds). Every audio output over the bluetooth speakers is delayed. Sometimes over 1sec delay!

Comment: This solution here solved the problem for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/171165/758645
However, the LogitechX100 only support ad2p_sink. Switch the second line to off and the others to ad2p_sink works very well for me!